# WiFi driver working but can't connect to any network

Tags: drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

I have just installed Ubuntu 18.04.4 today on my sister's Meccer YA13Q20. I am try to connect to any WiFi network but it's failing to connect. I have tried using another from lwfinger which I compiled manually. Here are the steps I followed

```
$ git clone  https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au.git
$ make
$ sudo make install 
$ sudo modprobe -r rtl8xxxu
$ sudo modprobe 8723au
```

Nothing is happening when I do this. But when I do this `sudo modprobe rtl8xxxu` the driver is loaded and WiFi device starts but it cannot cannot connect to any network. Is there any other way around this?

This is the information I get when I run `usb-devices` command.

```
Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=04 Cnt=05 Dev#=  8 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.10 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0bda ProdID=b720 Rev=02.00
S:  Manufacturer=Realtek
S:  Product=802.11n WLAN Adapter
S:  SerialNumber=00e04c000001
C:  #Ifs= 3 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 6 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)
```

Comment: What is the wireless device?

Comment: It's a realtek device

Comment: Which Realtek device? Is it a USB device?

Comment: Yes it is a USB device.

Comment: I have edited the question. I added more information.

Comment: So why you are installing a wrong driver? It is not an rtl8723au device.

Comment: I thought the issue is related to the driver installed by default because it can't connect to any network.

Comment: It is an rtl8723bu

Comment: How did you figure out it that it's an rtl8723bu

Comment: `ProdID=b720` see?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115178/discussion-between-chaulap-and-pilot6).